# Do you know of a useful web sandbox for Swift?

Tags: swift, ibm-swift-sandbox

I miss IBM's Swift sandbox. I loved being able to try out quick ideas without have to fire up the Xcode monster.

I have been trying to use https://iswift.org/playground but because one can't use import, there just isn't much I can do with it.

Or, if you have any other ideas about lightweight alternatives to Xcode, for example, if you have ideas about how to get Foundation at least available on iswift... that would be great too.

Or, Is there a way to open Playgrounds without all of Xcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite sandbox is http://online.swiftplayground.run/

You can also use `Import` there and you can even select the Swift-Version. This is very useful!
`Foundation` is imported by **default**.

And you can even download the .`swift` file or `.playground` file

Comment: I have tried this before but I can't get it to work, neither in Safari or Firefox. When I press Run, nothing happens.

Comment: Hm thats weird. Because it works everytime for me, I used it on Safari,Chrome and Firefox. Do you have JavaScript enabled? An oh, btw, this sandbox is powered by IMB Cloud

Comment: It works for me on iPhone with iOS12 too. I think the problem is, that it only use http and dont https. Maybe check your settings in your browser

Comment: It works at home. So I guess it must be our firewall at work. Thanks. I will give it a try.